# OpenCV cvWriteString not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, opencv

```
for (i = 0; i < nPersons; i++) {
    String varname = "personName_" + (i + 1);
    cvWriteString(
              fileStorage, // fs
          varname, // name
              personNames.get(i), // string
              0); // quote
}
```

I'm trying to use openCV to do some facial recognition. This is part of code that I've found from javaCV sample. 
The compiler always complains about :

> The method cvWriteString(opencv_core.CvFileStorage, String, String, int) in the type opencv_core is not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.CvFileStorage, String, Object, int)

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personNames.get(i) returns an object, not a String. You have to cast it to let the compiler know you'll be passing a String in.

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < nPersons; i++) {
    String varname = "personName_" + (i + 1);
    cvWriteString(fileStorage, // fs
                  varname, // name
                  (String) personNames.get(i), // string
                  0); // quote
}
```